# How to find parent of child element by class - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, children

I've reviewed similar questions, but I'm still a newbie at Jquery and am having trouble understanding the solutions, and would appreciate an exact example.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="random">
       <span class="child">
```

I want to change the .innerHtml content of "child" only if child possesses a parent (not immediate parent) whose class is "parent".

I know for sure that the "child" class will exist, but I do NOT know if the "parent" class exists on the page.

There may be multiple "child" class elements, and could be multiple "parent" class elements.  If any of "child" children possess "parent", they all need to acted upon.

The nested child spans are created by another library, so I do not have access to give them Ids, or anything.

I expect a behavior something like this, but obviously, this code is not right:

```
var children = document.getElementsByClass('child');

foreach(children as child){
   if (child.hasParent(.parent)){
        child.innerHTML = "New Text";
}
```

1. What is the proper way to do this, and
2. How do I prevent problems if there is no "parent" element in the page?

Comment: You tageed this jQuery, did you want a jQuery answer or a vanilla javascript answer?

Comment: I'll take either.  I probably prefer jQuery - whichever is easier and most proper.  I'm already using jQuery on the page.

Comment: jQuery is still popular but it's starting to become completely redundant for its role as a DOM normalizer/simplifier/auto-iterator. Also the reasoning behind not upgrading animation to requestAnimationFrame is kind of appalling to me as a user. I still miss it when its not there occasionally even when I intentionally don't add it to newer apps. But it's worth learning the core DOM stuff and the querySelectorAll APIs even if you'll typically use JQ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to find all elements with class "child" that have a parent with class "parent":

```
var children = document.querySelectorAll(".parent .child");
```

That gives you back a list of nodes that match, possibly an empty list:

```
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i)
  children[i].innerHTML = "New Text";
```

The `.querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` methods work (mostly) even in IE8, so this approach is pretty universal.

Since you tagged the question with jQuery, you could do it with that library too:

```
$(".parent .child").html("New Text");
```

That will update all of the "child" elements with a "parent" parent node; jQuery does all the iteration for you.

Comment: That's perfect!  It works great.  Thanks - I knew there had to be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery

```
$(".parent .child").html("New Text");
```

This will change the html content of any `.child` elements but only if they have a parent `.parent` - not just direct parent.

Comment: Thanks for the specifically jQuery answer.  This is so much easier than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

More Shorter code in Vanilla JS:

```
var children = document.querySelectorAll(".parent .child");
[].forEach.call(children, function(elem){
   elem..innerHTML = "New Text";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually don't want to insert text when `.parent` is the immediate parent. That's one operation where JQ might still have something on querySelector although odds are good there's probably something css querySelector supports I'm forgetting about.

```
$('.parent .child').not('.parent > .child').html('stuff');
```

If you ever need to identify any non-immediate `.parent` parent nodes you can do this:

```
$('.child').parent().parents('.parent');
//or ... '.parent:first'); just for the first one it finds.
```

Oh, and one thing that might help performance a fair bit is to add the html tag if it can be relied upon, e.g.

```
$('div.parent p.child');
```

I think JQ still uses the old DOM stuff under the hood for performance and finding stuff by tag name first narrows things down a lot faster than just by class in that scenario.